# how to make it so only keys show in dict- python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so the user enters a txt file they want read and the text file contains generally

```
a eats b
b eats c
c eats d

f_web = open(input('enter text wanted evaluated:'))

def web(enter text):
    food_web = f_web
    tuple_data = []
    for line in food_web:
        a = line.strip().split()
        tuple_data.append((a[0].strip(), a[-1].strip()))
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for x, y in tuple_data:
            output[x].append(y)
    print ('Predators and Prey:')
    for Predators, Prey in output.items():
        values = ' , '.join(Prey)
        print ('\t{} eats {}'.format(Predators, values))
     return web
    web(f_web)
```

i want my program to display the current stuff and afterwards display which predators are only predators and are never eaten. so like this

never eaten:

a

Comment: Open(input...) Will probably raise an error...

Comment: i edited it, but how would u recommend i change it?

Comment: Call for the input in one line, and `open` the input in a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using a `dictionary` for that:

```
fl = str(input('Enter text wanted evaluated: '))

with open(fl, 'r') as f:
f = f.read().split('\n')

f_dict = {}

for i in f:
    i = i.split()
    if i[0] in f_dict:
        f_dict[i[0]].append(i[2])
    else:
        f_dict[i[0]] = [i[2]]

a = []
for i in f_dict:
    for j in f_dict.values():
        if i in j:
            break
        a.append(i)

a = list(set(a))

for i in f_dict:
    print i+' eats '+', '.join(f_dict[i])

print('')
print('Never Eaten')
for i in a:
    print i

[Out]:
a eats b, d, c
c eats d
b eats c, d

Never Eaten
a
```

Comment: because i also want the original sequence of who eats who displayed before who is never eaten.

Comment: @user3531022, There. Works now. Simply added print statement.

Comment: the output for your code is really weird try to run my program it runs so the first part is displayed in proper sentences and punctuation instead of just a list of keys and values

Comment: @user3531022, Is that better now?

Comment: kind of but in ur program how would i change it so instead of just saying a eats b a eats c a eats d , i construct a full sentence saying a eats b, c , and d

Comment: @user3531022, I have updated my answer. If my answer was helpful, would you mind [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? Thank you.

Comment: it was helpful but not fully correct as there are some syntax errors in it, and also would this code work if instead of just letters like a and b the prey and predator were replaced with full names like lion or wolf

Comment: @user3531022, Yes it would work. As long as the sentence is `word<space>eats<space>word`

Comment: it doesnt work displaying this     if i[0] in f_dict:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user3531022, Did you take the code, precisely as shown because I tried running it and it worked. Maybe there is something wrong in your text file?

Comment: yes but i had to indent the 3rd line because of a syntax error

Comment: no instead of a eats b, b eats c etc.... i replaced it with Lion eats Deer Lion eats Hyena Hyena eats Deer and got an error saying     if i[0] in f_dict:
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Open file and read each line, splitting by `'eats'`.
2. Append the first value to a list named `predator`, if it hasn't already been in `prey` (if it hadn't been the 2<sup>nd</sup> value), and if it is in `predator` and it is is prey, remove it from `predator` and at it to `prey`.
3. Print all the values in `predator`.

   ```
   open('file.txt')
   predators = []
   eaten = []
   for lines in file:
       lines = lines.split('eats')
       predator, prey = lines
       if predator not in eaten:
           predators.append(predator)
       if prey in predator:
           del(predator[prey])
       eaten.append(prey)
   print 'Never eaten:'
   for k in predators:
       print k
   ```

Runs as:

```
Never eaten:
a
```